# arcpy.Statistics_analysis for multivalue parameter

Tags: arcpy, statistics, error-000725

I made this script to calculate the sum for a selected field after a query definition is defined. I have some issues now, to do with a multivalue field. The code is:

```
import arcpy

Layer1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
Tabela1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) 
Estado = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  
Ano = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
Saida = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
stats = []

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):   
    lyr.name = Layer1
    lyr.definitionQuery = """UF IN ({})""".format(Estado)

for field in arcpy.ListFields(Tabela1):
    if field.name in (Ano):
        stats.append([field.name, "SUM"])
        arcpy.Statistics_analysis(Layer1, Saida, stats, "")
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

I entered a multivalue parameter but the output show me only one field sum. The other problem is even table do not exist the console show me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\AgroBD.gdb\M6a.py", line 18, in <module>
    arcpy.Statistics_analysis(Layer1, Saida, stats, "")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line      1160, in Statistics
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000725: Output Table: Dataset F:\AgroBD.gdb\c1 already exists.
Failed to execute (Statistics).

Failed to execute (Consulta).
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense, you get a `lyr` set it's name to `Layer1` then run the statistic on `Layer1`, but all layers are named `Layer1`...?

Comment: Yes it`s works well. The problem in this code is when I put a parameter with multivalue and how to do the arcpy.Statistics_analysis with a multivalue field.

Comment: Also you need to expand out your LIST `Ano` into a list of lists. Split() returns a LIST.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: As always look at the help! Code [Sample 3](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) shows you how to build the parameter

Comment: This sample do not work well for my code. I tried to adapt, I will edit my post

Comment: Your call to Statistics_analysis is WITHIN the loop that creates the list `stats`, remove it from the loop.

Comment: I removed from the loop but do not work...says ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000735: Statistics Field(s): Value is required

Comment: Have you actually removed it from the code? If so put it back, place it _outside_ the loop. So in your case remove two levels of indentation.

Comment: I did this but it’s not working

Comment: Please keep editing your question so that it only shows the current [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that you wish to present and its error.